# How to create a dynamic context menu in android?

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

```
@Override  
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Selection Options");  
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Remove");  
    }
```

I want my menu to say "Remove AAPL"

I would get the string AAPL from my array adapter, but I am not sure how I can access my array adapters index from this method.

Answer (score 5):

Example if you are using listviews with custom object:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    MyObject obj = (MyObject) myListView.getItemAtPosition(info.position);

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Selection Options");  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Remove " + obj.name); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Cast `menuInfo` to an [`AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.html) object. From there, you can get the `position` and `id` of the item in the `ListView` that was long-tapped.

Comment: AdapterContextMenuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo; //cant be resolved... can you show me how to cast it properly?

Comment: @Sheehan Alam: It is not `AdapterContextMenuInfo`. It is `AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo`. See this sample project: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants/

Comment: The example only works onContextItemSelected, I am doing something similar there. How about for onCreateContextMenu? I can't cast the ContextMenuInfo...

Comment: @Sheehan Alam: Why not? The object should be an `AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo`, since there are only two concrete implementations of `ContextMenuInfo`, and you are not working with an `ExpandableListView`.