# How to enable/disable context menu items on runtime

Tags: java, android

I want to enable/disable items depending certain conditions...

With options menu you can do:

```
.setGroupEnabled(0, false);
```

But i don't know how to do this with context menu

How can I do that?

Thanks

EDIT: These items are in inflated menu

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify/create a context menu at runtime from within the `onCreateContextMenu` method.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    MyObject obj = (MyObject) myListView.getItemAtPosition(info.position);

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Selection Options");  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Remove " + obj.name); 
}
```

Here is some sample code I took from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631967/how-to-create-a-dynamic-context-menu-in-android). By overriding this method you can modify the menu as its created. Just add some conditionals within here to control your different scenerios.

Comment: But... if I want to disable an option of an inflated menu?

Comment: You mean once the menu is already inflated? I don't believe you can remove a menu option in real time once the menu is displayed to the user since the view is already rendered. There is no invalidate method for a menu like there are with other view times in which you can refresh. You can only change dynamicaly each time it is inflated.

Comment: Ok, one more question. Which is more efficient in terms of performance? Inflated menus or menu.add?

Comment: Not entirely sure but I cannot image there is that big of a difference. You're either pasring basic XML group/item or adding directly.

Comment: @user222 can use alaerdialog.setItem, it has the similar appearance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can enable/disable Context menu item at runtime inside `onCreateContextMenu` method.

Below is an example:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(@NonNull ContextMenu menu, @NonNull View v,
                                @Nullable ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Title text");

    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.history_overflow_item_menu, menu); // Your menu xml file

    // Get menu item using index and set enablity with your conditions.
    if (abc == bcd) {
        menu.getItem(0).setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```