# Change menu items dynamically

Tags: android, menu

**I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404092/how-to-enable-disable-context-menu-items-on-runtime?lq=1) question, but it didn't help me.** 
The problem is: I'm parsing a website, some posts are personal ones and the other are group posts. If it's a group post, I want to show 2 menuItems in context menu - "Show author's blog" and "Show group's page" and if it's only personal post, only "Show author's blog" menu Item must be shown.

````

```
@Override
     public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)     {
     super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
     menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Open author's blog" );
     menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Open group's page"); 
 }

 @Override 
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
     AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
     switch(item.getItemId()) {
     case 1:
        << some code >> 
         break;
     }
     return true; 
 }
```

````

I can't understand, how can I get this (MenuItem item) in OnCreateContextMenu method. I hope this way I would be able to set some menu items visible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to adapt the previous answer to your code.

The `onCreateContextMenu` callback is triggered BEFORE the creation of the ContextMenu, and it's within this callback that you need choose to create (or not create) the items of your ContextMenu. So, what you need to do is to retrieve the object associated with the cell of your adapter (the cell that triggered the callback), and then, programmatically create the items of the menu, depending on the type of the post.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    Post post = (Post) myListView.getItemAtPosition(info.position);

    if (post.getPostType() == PostType.Personal) {
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Show author's blog");
    else if (post.getPostType() == PostType.Group) {
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Show author's blog");
        menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Show group's page");
    }
}
```

Comment: My context menu is created by listview, some of elements there may be group posts and some are personal ones. So, context menu will be every time re-created properly depending on posttype?

Comment: Yes, your contextMenu will be re-created each time you perform a long press on an element of the listView. So, you need to find which row of the listView is selected, find if this row is associated with a group or a personal post and then, add only the items that you need in your contextMenu.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't understand, how can I get this (MenuItem item) in
>   OnCreateContextMenu method. I hope this way I would be able to set
>   some menu items visible or not.

To obtain specific `MenuItem` you can use:

```
menu.getItem(<position>);
menu.findItem(<id>);
```

where first method uses position of item in menu (its calculated from top to bottom from zero to n). So in your case first item (author) has index 0 and second has index 1.

Second method is very useful if you're specified menu in XML file - then you can obtain items based on their ids.

Additionally to get some extra information from element for which menu was displayed you could use:

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
View child = info.targetView;
```

Then based on gained information you can show or hide item(s) in ContextMenu.